# Is PCTeX store still working?

Tags: mtpro, mathtime

I'm wondering if I can buy MathTimePro 2 from the PCTeX store as for 2022. If I purchase the license will it arrive to me? Even Chrome says that the store is not secure. If it is not working, where can I buy a spare copy? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not having any trouble with accessing the web site through Firefox: https://pctex.com/v6info.html

Comment: Me neither, the problem is that many download links are dead, so I want to be sure that if I pay the license will arrive to my email

Answer (score 2):

I placed on order on May 13th 2023 and received a download link via email.